# MVC Validation - Issue checking DB records for matching values before posting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, crud

Hi everyone I cant seem to figure out how to check a record before creating a new post in MVC

When a user creates a "SuperMember" I want it to check IF that "Character" has already been assigned that "membership" already aka a duplicate record. Each Character can have many memberships but not the same one.

Heres my code -

**MODELS**

```
public class Character
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CharacterID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Hero Alias")]
        public string HeroAlias { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SuperMembers> SuperMembers { get; set; }

    }


public class Membership
    {
        [Key]
        public int MembershipID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Membership Name")]
        public string MembershipName { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Membership Tyoe")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SuperMembers>SuperMembers { get; set; }

    }


public class SuperMembers
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Membership Number")]
        public int SuperMembersID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Hero Alias")]
        public int CharacterID { get; set; }        
        public Character Character  { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Membership")]
        public int MembershipID { get; set; }
        public Membership Membership { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Column(TypeName = "money")]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Account Balance")]
        public decimal AccountBalance { get; set; }

    }
```

Then the Controller POST Method

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("SuperMembersID,CharacterID,MembershipID,AccountBalance")] SuperMembers superMembers)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var IfAlreadyExists = dbo.SuperMembers.Where(x => x.CharacterID == CharacterID && x.MembershipID == MembershipName).FirstOrDefault();

                if (IfAlreadyExists == null)
                {
                    //POST
                }
                else
                {
                    //Return ERROR "Sorry this Membership already exists"
                }

                _context.Add(superMembers);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["CharacterID"] = new SelectList(_context.Character, "CharacterID", "HeroAlias", superMembers.CharacterID);
            ViewData["MembershipID"] = new SelectList(_context.Membership, "MembershipID", "MembershipName", superMembers.MembershipID);
            return View(superMembers);
        }
```

The dbo in "dbo.SuperMembers" is underlined too, im using a local db for this little practice project so not sure if thats also a factor?
Im fairly new to this, this is my first StackOverflow post so apologies if ive missed anything obvious - Would appreciate any pointers. Thanks

Comment: How do you define "similar"? How similar until they are considered a duplicate?

Comment: sorry i meant a duplicate - ill edit the question :)

Comment: You'll either have to make a query to see if the record exists (then perform the next steps) or you can let the database enforce the uniqueness and reject the insertion. As for "dbo", have you declared dbo as a variable?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state?redirectedfrom=MSDN#insert-or-update-pattern

Comment: I did try something similar and managed to get it working, so when you created a 'new' post if you assigned a character a duplicate membership, it overwrote the original. But i decided this wasnt quite achieving the same outcome id like. I think from a user perspective itd be better to see an error thrown and a duplicate membership warning.